# Making Polygon with Python MatPlotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I tried to make a polygon with this code but it appears me to the polygon. I need one polygon.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [4, 1, 2]
y = [1, 2, 1]
z = [0, 2, 1]

plt.fill(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

If you run this code, it will print 2 polygons in two colors. I need only one polygon with one color only. can anyone please fix me this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the color of the polygons to be the same:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [4, 1, 2]
y = [1, 2, 1]
z = [0, 2, 1]

plt.fill(x, y, z, c='C0')
plt.show()
```

[image: Filled polygon]

I'm not completely certain why the preceding code works like it does. `plt.fill()` is used for plotting 2D polygons, and the third argument should be the color, so what you should really write is this:

```
x = [4, 1, 0, 2]
y = [1, 2, 0, 1]

plt.fill(x, y, c='C0')
plt.show()
```

(which gives the same plot)

[image: Filled polygon]

Comment: `plt.fill(x,y,z)` is the same as calling `plt.fill(x,y); plt.fill(z)`. You can in fact draw as many filled shapes as you like, though for better readability I would propose to always define x and y, like `plt.fill(x1,y1, x2,y2, x3, y3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!